# Blender python : How to use environment variable?

Tags: python

I did this :

```
import os
print(os.environ['BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS'])
```

and got error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\blender-2.80.0-git.16fc62e15f0-windows64\2.80\python\lib\os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS'
```

can someone show me the correct syntax ? and how to check if BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS is available in the environment var ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, What error do you get?

Comment: @JeffUK i've just updated my post with error message. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like more of a general programming question than a Blender question...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-do-i-access-environment-variables-from-python seems to answer it?  Maybe the second answer is more what you're looking for.

Comment: You can check `if 'BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS' in os.environ`, but yeah - this is a python question rather than a blender question.